# React State is not getting update before assertion even acting inside act function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

Why below unit test case is failing? I have a similar situation in real-world, but here, I am testing a simplified version of it.

I am expecting that assertions should execute after **act** complete the state update of hook, but its not behaving that way. Though state is getting update, after assertions executes.

Please suggest if there is any other way to test such situation.

**Code**

```
 const HookForTest = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  const updateDataFromOutside = toData => {
    setData(toData);
  };

  return [data, updateDataFromOutside];
};
```

**Unit Test**

```
describe('HookForTest', () => {
  test('should change state on calling updateDataFromOutside function ', async () => {
    let hookData;

    testHook(() => {
      hookData = HookForTest();
    });

    let [data, updateDataFromOutside] = hookData;

    await act(async () => {
      updateDataFromOutside('testData');
    });

    expect(data).toEqual('testData');
  });
});
```

I am using a few utility functions for testing custom hook, below is code:

```js
export const TestHook = ({callback}) => {
  callback();
  return null;
};

export const testHook = callback => {
  mount(<TestHook callback={callback} />);
};
```

**Test Result**

```
 ● HookForTest › should change state on calling updateDataFromOutside function 

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "testData"
    Received: ""

      178 |     });
      179 | 
    > 180 |     expect(data).toEqual('testData');
```

Comment: What is the value of **act** ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `let [data, updateDataFromOutside] = hookData;` locks the value of `data` to be what its original value was.  Even if something like `hookData[0] = 'something else'` was called, the value of `data` would still be `''`.

Changing the test to something like this should work

```js
describe('HookForTest', () => {
  test('should change state on calling updateDataFromOutside function ', async () => {
    let data;
    let updateDataFromOutside;

    testHook(() => {
      let hookData = HookForTest();
      data = hookData[0]
      updateDataFromOutside = hookData[1]
    });

    await act(async () => {
      updateDataFromOutside('testData');
    });

    expect(data).toEqual('testData');
  });
});
```